# How to implement constructor wrapping in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

This is what I'm trying to do (in Java 1.6):

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setSomeData();
    b.doSomethingElse();
    this(b);
  }
  public Foo(Bar b) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Compiler says:

```
call to this must be first statement in constructor
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    this(makeBar());
  }
  public Foo(Bar b) {
    // ...
  }
  private static Bar makeBar() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setSomeData();
    b.doSomethingElse();
    return b;
  }
}
```

The `makeBar` method should be static, since the object corresponding to `this` is not available at the point you are calling the method.

By the way, this approach has the advantage that it *does* pass a fully initialized `Bar` object to the `Foo(Bar)`.  (@RonU notes that his approach does not.  That of course means that his `Foo(Bar)` constructor cannot assume that its `Foo` argument is in its final state.  This can be problematical.)

Finally, I agree that a static factory method is a good alternative to this approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the "default constructor" as a static factory method:

```
public class Foo {
  public static Foo createFooWithDefaultBar() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setSomeData();
    b.doSomethingElse();
    return new Foo(b);
  }
  public Foo(Bar b) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like it says, a call to this() must be the first thing to happen in a constructor. Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    this(new Bar());
    Bar b = getBar();
    b.setSomeData();
    b.doSomethingElse();
  }
  public Foo(Bar b) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: No argument about that. For me, these situations often turn into my asking do-I-really-want-that-constructor, and usually the answer is no, as I think this smells wrong. I'd rather have the instantiator pass in a fully configured Bar (second constructor) and move on.

Comment: This won't work because `Foo(Bar b)` may do some operations with `b`, which have to happen after initialization of `b`